# Why is Segmentation fault (core dumped) occurring

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    FILE* ptr;
    int cha, charac = 0, lines = 0, spaces = 0;
    char ch;
    fp = fopen("f.txt", "r");

    while (ch != EOF) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c", ch);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("fi.txt", "w+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2021);
    fclose(fp);

    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Can't Open File");

    else {

        while ((cha = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            charac++;

            if (ch == ' ')
                spaces++;

            if (ch == '\n')
                lines++;
        }

        fclose(fp);
        printf("Character %d\n", charac);
        printf("Spaces %d\n", spaces);
        printf("Lines %d\n", lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly not the case of the sigsegv, but `cha=fgetc(fp)` and `if(ch == ' ')` looks strange, but without a complete program it's impossible to be totally sure of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Aaqib Declare the variable cha as having the type int. int cha;

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Still the same error

Comment: @IanBush I have uploaded the complete code
First I read a file then I opened a file with "w+" to write things then after that trying to figure out the total number of lines spaces and characters

Comment: @Aaqib You need to declare ch as having the type int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The part where "w+" is used to open the file  -- Error starts there!

Comment: @Aaqib You need to check whether the file was opened successfully that is that fp is not equal to NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Even after declaring cha and ch as int type
Error remains the same

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you. The files were not opening
You're a life saver

Comment: __Always__ check if `fopen` succeeds. `fopen` is one of the functions that fails most. Also for your next question learn how to format code properly. It's easy and it will take you only a few minutes.

Comment: ....and when you declare ch as an int, as directed by Vlad, the 'while (ch != EOF) {' check may fail the first time because you have not loaded ch and so it's value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to write a code that read a file, count the lines/spaces/chars and print it to screen. Then write an other file which include "we are in 2021". Right? OK the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char * *argv, char * *envp) {
    FILE *fRead;
    FILE *fWrite;
    int characters = 0, lines = 0, spaces = 0;
    fRead = fopen("/Users/Shared/CommonAll/file1.txt", "r");
    if (fRead == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Could not open the SOURCE file!");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        char singleChar;
        while(1){
            singleChar = fgetc(fRead);
            if(singleChar == EOF || (int)(singleChar) == -1){
                break;
            }
            else if (singleChar == ' '){
                spaces++;
            }
            else if ((int) (singleChar) == 13) {
                lines++;
            }
            else {
                characters++;
            }
            printf("%c", singleChar);
        }
    }
    fclose(fRead);

    fWrite = fopen("/Users/Shared/CommonAll/file2.txt", "w+");
    if (fWrite == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: Could not open the TARGET file!");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(fWrite, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2021);
    fclose(fWrite);

    printf("\nCharacter %d\n", characters);
    printf("Spaces %d\n", spaces);
    printf("Lines %d\n", lines);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to put a `return()` in the statement run if `if (fRead == NULL)` is true, there's no need for the `else`.